# Calculated (calculation based on other columns) IF OR ISBLANK AND Sharepoint Lists error formula

Tags: list, error, calculated-column-formula, formula, isblank

Can anyone help? I can't work out why this is erroring. this section **=IF(OR(ISBLANK[Tech £]),"",** at the start in bold makes it error.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Tech £])),"",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="No"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="No"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"£23",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"£40",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="No"),"Oops")))))))))
```

Comment: this is formula is was using (which worked) then I wanted to blank the unused cells

Comment: =IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Paid in Full",[Tech Pack]="No"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"Oops",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="N/A",[Tech Pack]="No"),"0",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="Pack 2=PC Only"),"£23",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="Pack 1=Full Kit"),"£40",IF(AND([Tech Pay Type]="Monthly",[Tech Pack]="No"),"Oops")))))))))

Comment: What is the error? As per your existing formula, the column name 'Tech £' was not used before, are you sure it exists?